# Why can’t I set innerHTML on my custom HTML tag in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, innerhtml

I have a problem with IE and innerHTML. Please check out the following code.

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName("mytag");
h.item(0).tagName;
var d = document.body.innerHTML;
h.item(0).innerHTML = "<div id='' style='height:auto'><textarea id=''></textarea><br/><button id=''>Post</button></div>";
```

Please note that I changes the ID's.

The above code works well in Firefox, but not in IE.

```
 h.item(0).innerHTML = "<div id='' style='height:auto'><textarea id=''></textarea><br/><button id=''>Post</button></div>";
```

This line making me trouble. `mytag` is a custom one.

I am stuck here, please help.

Thank you.

Comment: IE won't support custom tags as DOM elements so you're out of luck. You'll have to use valid HTML tags like `<div>` or `<span>` (or any other tag) instead of `mytag`.

Comment: Thank you ,But is there anyway to to do this ?

Comment: Maybe by applying proper `namespace` as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531076(v=vs.85).aspx) but I'm not sure it will work either.

Comment: How i can force other website owners to use proper namespace ? the code is not for my website,it works like a API.

Comment: No you can't force them to do such a thing.

Comment: hehe,okk,i managed it with `createElement`,but now i cant bind events to newly generated `button` :?

Comment: What button? Anyway to attach click event have such code: `button.onclick = function() { alert("I was clicked"); };`

Comment: i managed it with attachEvent and addeventeListner.

Comment: Hai @tereško ,Thanks for the link ,its solved.

Answer (score 3):

`mytag` won't be recognized by IE, you will have to create them for IE to know using:

```
document.createElement('mytag');
```

Or alternatively, use tags such as `<div>`, etc

Comment: `var h = document.getElementsByTagName("mytag");
 h= h.item(0).tagName;alert(h);` - this work well,but i cant set its innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

use document.all.elementID.getElementsByTagName(param1)

Comment: That's not true. The `getElementById` is very basic, the only problem with old IE version (7 and less) is that it will also look for element with such *name* but it will also bring back element with that ID just fine. See more details [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t10)

Comment: Ok, I have confined it wrong, Thank you for your advise which is helpfull.